# how to get country code from Mobile number in php

Tags: php, country-codes, mobile-country-code

Is there any way to find the country code of a phone number in PHP? If I have **+971526457896**, I will receive the country code as **+971** (if its United Arab Emirates).

Any suggestions please, how to do that?

Comment: Is country code always the first three digits of the string?

Comment: i have more than 100 mobile numbers in database i want to go through each number and find the countrycode  is it possible

Answer (score 1):

It's been a long since you asked this question but I'm going to provide an option to do this for future references.

I had exactly the same situation: all my code+phonenumber are saved on my database in an unique table field...

In order to recognize the international code I use this on my website:

https://github.com/Bluefieldscom/intl-tel-input

Whatever phone number you provide using '+' before your entire phonenumber, it does the correct country code detection.

So, you can use the code database on this code:
github.com/Bluefieldscom/intl-tel-input/blob/master/src/js/data.js

> The database is the clue of this algorithm, it defines levels of
>   priority for country code coincidences.

And the check de logic in order to perform your own code:
github.com/Bluefieldscom/intl-tel-input/blob/master/src/js/intlTelInput.js

> U should probably go with the getNumber function.

In any case, using this database, anyone should be able to make a new code in any language.

Good luck!